# Button Visibility in WPF at startup

Tags: c#, button, wpf-controls, visibility

I have some button that I want them to be hidden when the wpf loads up.
I use this:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        mySendButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        myReceiveButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;                                                
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

But the above generating an error. i think I wrote them not at the right place.
Can I get a help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InitializeComponent` Method initializes the components, in your case buttons. Your buttons before `InitializeComponent` call is `null` because they are not initialized and setting its visibility throws the exception.

That's why in some languages it is written

```
//Add any code after the InitializeComponent() call.
```

You need to do

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mySendButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    myReceiveButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;                        
}
```

BTW, you can set the visibility in XAML like this.

```
<Button name="mySendButton" Content"Send" Visibiity="Collapsed" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are trying to access the button before it is initialized. This happens in the `InitializeComponent()` method. Either place the lines below that method:

```
public MainWindow()
{                                                
    InitializeComponent();
    mySendButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    myReceiveButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

or just use the appropriate property in the visual designer.